# How to include SQL code in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Prior to my main select statement, I first have to create a temporary table with thousands of lines (using a select statement to get these lines automatically is not feasible in my SQL Server environment), but working in that SQL query is a nightmare of readability, as my .sql file has thousands of lines :(

Is is possible to achieve something like this ?

```
include('actors_tables.sql') /*including all the insert code*/
select * from #temp_actors
```

instead of this ?

```
create table #temp_actors (firstname varchar(50), lastname varchar(50))
insert into #temp_actors values ('George','Clooney')
insert into #temp_actors values ('Bill','Murray')
insert into #temp_actors values ('Bruce','Willis')
... + 1000 inserts in thousands of lines
select * from #temp_actors
```

Seems to me like a basic simple feature but I can't find how to achieve this ...
The server is running SQL Server 2005, and I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

Thank you for your help !

Kris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command prompt, start up **sqlcmd**:

```
sqlcmd -S <server> -i C:\<your file name here>.sql -o
```

Or to run from sql server management studio use **xp_cmdshell** and **sqlcmd**:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell  'sqlcmd -S ' + @DBServerName + ' -d  ' + @DBName + ' -i ' + @FilePathName
```

Comment: unfortunately cp_cmdshell has been disabled for audit/security reasons in my work environment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) in command prompt with input file (use `sqlcmd -i actors_tables.sql` ).